# How to create an INCLUDE program?

Tags: include, abap, sap-bw, slt

Working with SAP will eventually lead to use of includes (same as includes in PHP)

When working e.g. with transformations (Transaction `RSA1`) you can **use** includes by using the `include <include_name>`. You can **create** an INCLUDE with the same statement if the *include_name* does not exists and you double click on the *include_name*.

However in other situations e.g. SLT you can also use includes but need to define them beforehand.

So **how to create an include** (transaction and steps)?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question that is covered in every introduction worth the time spent reading it - hence my down vote.

Answer (score 4):

Create an include:

1. Open Transaction SE38
2. type include name and click on create

OR

1. Open Transaction SE80
2. Choose Packet and Object name

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps below:

- Give new program name in SE38.
- Click `Create`.
- Choose Type `INCLUDE PROGRAM` in attributes section of dialog window
  that appears.